# Set properties on MsAccess database

Tags: c#, ms-access

How can I add/change properties to a created MsAccess database?

This is the code that I use for MsAccess creation:

```
 ADOX.Catalog catalog = new ADOX.Catalog();
    catalog.Create(accessConnectionString);

    //Create an Access connection and a command that we'll use
    OleDbConnection accessConnection = new OleDbConnection(accessConnectionString);
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = accessConnection;
    //command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    accessConnection.Open()
```

I would need to set/read/update some properties on it after the creation.

Is it possible?

Comment: "_This is the code that I use for MsAccess creation_" - No, it is not. You create nothing save a connection to an existing database. Please tell us what _exactly_ you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by "properties"?

Comment: When I run that code, new access database is always created. I am trying to set some properties on the access database itself. General properties, like author and similar. :)

Comment: I took a read-up on ADOX on the microsoft KB. As far as I have understand that, it _does_ create an access db but does not return a database object but rather sets a connection. Look into using Access Interop instead.

Comment: On a side note... why downvote on the question?

Comment: Wasn't me. Probably because your question is not MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and you haven't put enough effort into research first. Took me only a visit to Microsoft to know that ADOX probably is not made for such things.

Answer (score 2):

After some research, this is the code that sets up property on the msaccess database:

Note, for this to work please add this ([details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx#pialist)):

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao;


  var dbe = new DBEngine();
        var db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\access\mydb.accdb");

 //Initialize the properties 
        Dao.Property VERSION_PROPERTY = null;

 //Fill them with values
        VERSION_PROPERTY = db.CreateProperty("VERSION_PROPERTY",   Dao.DataTypeEnum.dbText, "Hello There. I am property of the database", true);
        //And append them
        db.Properties.Append(VERSION_PROPERTY);
```