# Excel VBA : check for an access flag (bolean) before continuing

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I run access macro from excel.

To be sure that the macro has finished loading I would like to use a flag drop by each access macro.

At the beginning of the access macro the flag is false and at the end it becomes true. This allows excel to wait for the right time.

How can I ask excel to check if the field of the access table "Flag" is true or false?

```
Sub GoIfTrue()

Dim appAccess As New Access.Application

Dim Flag As Boolean

Set appAccess = Access.Application

appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\file.accdb"

    If Flag.[FlagVBA] = True Then
        MsgBox "True"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm supposing that you want to store that flag in a configuration table.

For this simple case, you can use the built in function [DLookUp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.dlookup)
The 3rd parameter is used to filter by primary key and get the desired record.

```
Sub GoIfTrue()

    Dim appAccess As New Access.Application
    Dim Flag As Boolean

    Set appAccess = Access.Application

    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\file.accdb"


    If appAccess.DLookup("Flag", "ConfigTable", "ID = 1") = True Then
        MsgBox "True"
    End If

End Sub
```

Another option is store flags as [database properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-properties-property-dao). You can see an example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32758185/777551

Comment: Thats what I was looking for thanks a lot.